#  What IDEs support SBT  and Scala version 2.9.0

Tags: scala, ide, sbt, scala-2.9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which IDE for Scala 2.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615196/which-ide-for-scala-2-8)

I would like to know which IDEs specifically support Scala 2.9 and the sbt project ?

Comment: it's specific to sbt project and scala 2.9 version support.

Comment: Scala 2.9.0 Final [is released](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9483).

Comment: **netbeans-scala** plugin will be updated for Scala 2.9.0 over the weekend. **sbt-netbeans-plugin** cross-built for Scala 2.9.0 and updated for sbt 0.7.7 is already available: https://github.com/remeniuk/sbt-netbeans-plugin

Comment: i think they jumped the gun a bit on closing this item

Comment: yup, i want to know if there is eclipse support for sbt